# Link in new window

Tags: html, hyperlink, window

I have a problem. I want opening some link in a new window. I know, that is simply possible through href HTML tag, but there is problem, that I can´t use classic HTML tags. Is some method, how paste command for open in new window directly to the link? Something like hashtag command for jump to specific section on page. (Something like: http://www.example.com/part#newwindow)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.open` function to open the url in a new tab/window like this:

```
window.open( newurl, '_blank' );
```

Depending on the browser setting, this will either open a new window or a tab. Also, the browser might block opening a new tab depending on the settings.

Comment: Okay, I have slider in Wordpress template, but I don´t know, where are files for this slider in template and in settings is not choice for setting up opening in new window. That is page http://skusobnyserver.8u.cz/ and I want opening link only on first slide in new window. How to do it?

Comment: Yes, I am admin, I have access to everything.

Comment: Just bind a click event to the first slider and write this code in that event's callback

Comment: Okay, I am attaching link to the file with slider functions below. Is there some for edit for funtcionality with link in new window? Lnk: https://github.com/CherryFramework/CherryFramework/blob/master/slider.php